# Math.NET как правильно подключить к проекту Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

Возникли трудности с использованием библиотеки *Math.NET Numerics*.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно ее подключить к проекту?

Изложу по порядку:

Я создал проект *Class Library* (*dll*'ку), прописал методы класса и интерфейсы, все хорошо работает.

Теперь для написания математических расчетов подключаю *Math.Net* к проекту через *Solution Explorer* -> *References* -> *Manage NuGet Packages*...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Устанавливаю, после чего показывает что либа успешно установлена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Указываю в проекте

```
using MathNet.Numerics;
```

Меняю тип билда на `Release`, билдю проект..

В итоге компилятор выдает ошибку:

> *Error 2*  **Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'MathNet.Numerics' does not have a strong name**

В чем ошибка, как ее исправить или как правильно подключить *Math.NET Numerics*? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что библиотека Math.NET Numerics никем не подписана - а у вашей библиотеки подпись есть.

Проще всего убрать подпись у вашей библиотеки. Если же подпись вам нужна - вам придется собирать Math.NET Numerics из исходников.

Если вы используете гит - то лучше всего форкнуть исходники Math.NET Numerics, добавив туда использование подписи. После чего этот форк можно прицепить к основному проекту как субмодуль.

Если вы не используете гит - то проще всего будет скачать исходники, добавить туда подпись, побилдить их - после чего утянуть к себе итоговую dll.

Наиболее красивое решение получится если у вас есть локальный репозиторий пакетов nuget. В таком случае можно, исправив Math.NET Numerics, собрать пакет и положить его в локальный репозиторий под тем же именем - в таком случае, в основном проекте никаких изменений не потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за информацию. В общем я нашел утилиту Strong-Name Signer https://brutaldev.com/post/net-assembly-strong-name-signer, указал ей dll'ку. После чего комплилятор перестал ругаться и это решило мою проблему.

Comment: Если вы используете какую либо систему контроля версий - это в корне неверное решение. Если нет - да, так тоже сойдет.